# Сделал код на добавление в автозагрузку, после перезагрузки программа открывается но с ошибкой

Tags: c#

Сделал код на добавление в автозагрузку, после перезагрузки программа открывается но с ошибкой, что приложение не отвечает и две кнопки завершить и отладка приложения. Подскажите в чем проблема? Стоит Windows 10 x64, при запуске той же программы и по тому же пути что и в автозагрузке ошибок нету...

Comment: Ну так нажмите отладка и смотрите на ошибку. А так нам лишь гадать придется из миллиона возможных комбинаций что же у вас там не так... Предположу, что у вас указаны неверно пути до файлов, которые привязаны к рабочей директории и после перезапуска эта рабочая директория не та, что у вашего приложения, а значит и файл найти там не может (ванга в деле).

Comment: Вангую, что это winforms, но это не точно.